# Asking For Letters of Recommendation

Tags: recommendation-letter, internship, science

I am applying for multiple internships over the summer and most of them require 2 LOR's, is it okay to ask one professor to write me a LOR for each? I am a freshman and don't have many teachers who could write me a recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Ask a couple of professors who best know your work and think highly of you. Tell them when you first ask that there will be several letters for different internships. If they know in advance then they can easily do it, even if each needs a bit of tailoring. Ask early but follow up a week or so before they are due.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the requirements of your internship. If it requires academic recommendation, it is best to ask your professors. Professors here does not mean they are really "professors". You can ask your current lecturers/tutors who know you the most or you get a high score in that modules.

If it does not require specific people, you can ask your previous employer to write one of the letters of Recommendation.

Good luck with your application!